# Recover JSON incorrectly written to CSV as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with a column which consists of free form addresses and I use Google Geocoder API to normalize them

```
def normalize(address):
    r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my-key&address={}'.format(address))
    jsn = r.json()
    return jsn
tqdm.pandas()
df['json_address'] = df['address'].apply(normalize)
```

If I access the address with `df.loc[0]['json_address']` I get proper output

```
{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Магазин "Рябинушка',
     'short_name': 'Магазин "Рябинушка',
     'types': ['establishment', 'point_of_interest']},
    {'long_name': '13А', 'short_name': '13А', 'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'Ulitsa Burlaki',
     'short_name': 'Ulitsa Burlaki',
     'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Moskovskiy',
     'short_name': 'Moskovskiy',
     'types': ['locality', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Tyumensky District',
     'short_name': 'Tyumensky District',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
    {'long_name': "Tyumenskaya oblast'",
     'short_name': "Tyumenskaya oblast'",
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Russia',
     'short_name': 'RU',
     'types': ['country', 'political']},
    {'long_name': '625501', 'short_name': '625501', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
   'formatted_address': 'Магазин "Рябинушка, Ulitsa Burlaki, 13А, Moskovskiy, Tyumenskaya oblast\', Russia, 625501',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 57.1097691, 'lng': 65.4274889},
    'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 57.1111180802915,
      'lng': 65.42883788029151},
     'southwest': {'lat': 57.10842011970851, 'lng': 65.42613991970849}}},
   'partial_match': True,
   'place_id': 'ChIJ2RCQRGpfuUMRitn4cW2shUg',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': '4C5G+WX Moskovskiy, Tyumen Oblast, Russia',
    'global_code': '9J974C5G+WX'},
   'types': ['street_address']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Then I write the output to csv and read it again

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep = '|', encoding = 'utf-16')
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep = '|', encoding = 'utf-16')
```

And accessing address again get the following, so I can not parse it as a dictionary.

```
'{\'results\': [{\'address_components\': [{\'long_name\': \'Магазин "Рябинушка\', \'short_name\': \'Магазин "Рябинушка\', \'types\': [\'establishment\', \'point_of_interest\']}, {\'long_name\': \'13А\', \'short_name\': \'13А\', \'types\': [\'street_number\']}, {\'long_name\': \'Ulitsa Burlaki\', \'short_name\': \'Ulitsa Burlaki\', \'types\': [\'route\']}, {\'long_name\': \'Moskovskiy\', \'short_name\': \'Moskovskiy\', \'types\': [\'locality\', \'political\']}, {\'long_name\': \'Tyumensky District\', \'short_name\': \'Tyumensky District\', \'types\': [\'administrative_area_level_2\', \'political\']}, {\'long_name\': "Tyumenskaya oblast\'", \'short_name\': "Tyumenskaya oblast\'", \'types\': [\'administrative_area_level_1\', \'political\']}, {\'long_name\': \'Russia\', \'short_name\': \'RU\', \'types\': [\'country\', \'political\']}, {\'long_name\': \'625501\', \'short_name\': \'625501\', \'types\': [\'postal_code\']}], \'formatted_address\': \'Магазин "Рябинушка, Ulitsa Burlaki, 13А, Moskovskiy, Tyumenskaya oblast\\\', Russia, 625501\', \'geometry\': {\'location\': {\'lat\': 57.1097691, \'lng\': 65.4274889}, \'location_type\': \'ROOFTOP\', \'viewport\': {\'northeast\': {\'lat\': 57.1111180802915, \'lng\': 65.42883788029151}, \'southwest\': {\'lat\': 57.10842011970851, \'lng\': 65.42613991970849}}}, \'partial_match\': True, \'place_id\': \'ChIJ2RCQRGpfuUMRitn4cW2shUg\', \'plus_code\': {\'compound_code\': \'4C5G+WX Moskovskiy, Tyumen Oblast, Russia\', \'global_code\': \'9J974C5G+WX\'}, \'types\': [\'street_address\']}], \'status\': \'OK\'}'
```

So my question is how I can use it as a dictionary again if I have no access to original data and need to deal with csv I read? I think I have looked through every question here at Stack Overflow and did not found the answer.

Comment: Don't use a csv to serialize this sort of data

Comment: Although, you should be able to simply use `ast.literal_eval` just stop trying to replace stuff, you that will create a *non valid literal* the whole purpose of the backspace is to create valid literals.

Comment: I already got it after the whole day of struggle. By the way, what is the right way to serialize it?

Comment: I question the sanity of using a dataframe here at all, but perhaps simple use `pickle`

Comment: You are my hero, I just used ```ast.literal_eval``` without replacement and it seems it works, can not believe it was so simple.
And I would appreciate if you tell how to properly handle and serialize such data

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some lines which raise the same error even without replacement, maybe there are some other options?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Please do not post images

Comment: I have updated the post with the example

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how that happened. This isn't really a [mcve]. It would help if you posted, at the very least, the original dict. I suspect that the csv writer is messing up the dictionary literal because of quote-characters. Again, you really shouldn't be using csv for this, it was never designed to serialize these sorts of complex data-structures, but simple, tabular numeric/text data. Use `pickle` to serialize your data-frame and forget about csv.

Comment: Can you also explain why are you using `pandas` here to begin with?

Comment: Updated the post. I use pandas as I have thousands of store with master data for which I need to normalize address. Is there better tool for it?

Comment: Thousands is nothing, and in any case, pandas provides no advantage for `object` dtypes. So yeah, Just don't use pandas. Just a list would work just fine, heck, if all you are doing is taking a single column of addresses and creating two columns, you don't even really need a list and can do thewhole thing lazily, in any case, your bottleneck is going to be the API.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but for now I should deal somehow with what I have

Comment: There's probably no good way, you've made the mistake of thinking that simply dumping the string representation of an object is a good way to serialize it, but it is not. I do not know of any good way to deal with this given your current situation.